# The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, twitter-fabric

I am getting the following error when trying to integrate Fabric into my Android app's Gradle file.

```
Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.
```

My Gradle files look like the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// Put Fabric plugin after Android plugin
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.snapwebdevelopment.scanhappy"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments:card-form:3.0.3'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile files('libs/org-apache-commons-codec.jar')
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'announce'
apply plugin: 'java'
```

And my top-level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I also added my API key in the manifest at the bottom right before my `</application>` tag. Do I need to reorder something in my Gradle files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot apply both the `com.android.application` and the `java` plugin in the same module.

**Remove** the line with `apply plugin: 'java'`

Answer (score 0):

```
         buildscript {
          repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
       }

  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

     repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      }
```

//and the last
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'